# Extension with image: How to get the full image path in the template?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

I have created a Typo3 extension using the Extension Builder. One of those fields is an image field.

When rendering an entity in the frontend I have access to this field like:

```
{entity.image} <!-- results in image.jpg without a path -->
```

But it only retrieves the name of the file. Now I could create a folder, where all images regarding this extension should be uploaded like:

```
fileadmin/user_upload/entity
```

Now I can wire it in the template like:

```
<img src=" fileadmin/user_upload/entity/{entity.image}" alt="{entity.name}">
```

This works fine **until** someone uses the image multiple time. In this case Typo3 will create an image and set **image_01.jpg**, **image_02.jpg** etc. in the backend. Of course those images don't exist in the newly created folder. It seems, that Typo3 creates a copy somewhere and uses the name from that copy.

So my questions are:

- How can I get the real image path in my template? Maybe somewhere in the controller?
- **OR** How can I stop Typo3 from creating those copies and increasing the number of each image?
- **OR** Does the image viewHelper `<f:image />` help here? If so, how?

This is an extbase/fluid based extension.

Comment: Which TYPO3 version are you using? 6.x or 4.x? The solution depends on it.

Comment: @lorenz I'm using as tagged verison 6.1.x - I found that Typo3 is copying the images into `uploads/tx_nameofextension`. Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a normal field of type "group" with internal_type "file", TYPO3 copies the file to

```
uploads/your_extension/
```

To prevent duplicates, it adds a numerical suffix to files with the same name (even if they are identical). So you should reference the file from there.

In TYPO3 6.x you might consider using the File Abstraction Layer. Basically you add an image field of FAL to your table/model and you will get a file browser and all the stuff you need to attach files to your record.

In your Fluid template you then have access to all FAL properties, such as file size, file extension etc.. See here for a tutorial:
http://keinerweiss.de/755-typo3-fal-in-einer-eigenen-extbasefluid-extension-einsetzen.html

Comment: Thanks for the hint using an abstraction layer.

Answer (score 1):

just for the record, its documented nowhere:

```
file extension (filetype): {yourfile.originalResource.originalFile.extension}
file size (filesize): {yourfile.originalResource.originalFile.size}
type?: {yourfile.originalResource.originalFile.type}
```